# Why does the autoscaling group not start new instances after instance refresh?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have a autoscaling group runnig and do an instance refresh. After two seconds, it says, it was successful and does not restart any instance.

I can see this by checking the start time of the instances of the autoscaling group.

What do I misunderstand about instance refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I just understood, that I need to uncheck *skip matching*. In that way , I can restart even when the current state of the configuration is correct.

Skip matchingInfo
To avoid replacing instances with the desired configuration, use skip matching. When an instance matches your desired launch template and any instance type overrides, it is not replaced